# setState not updating state object for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Consider the following code block:

```
{split.participants.map(friend => {
                        return <div key={Math.random()} className="form-check my-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                                <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox 
                                  onChange={(e) => {
                                    let temp = sharedByChecks
                                    const t = friend
                                    temp[t] = !temp[t]
                                    console.log("temp:", temp)
                                    setSharedByChecks(temp);
                                }} 
                                  checked={sharedByChecks[friend]} />} 
                                  label={friend} />
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    })}
```

Now for context, here is the description of the variables:

1. `split` is an object which has a string array called `participants`. this is working as expected as the structure rendered is fine (map variable `friend` is working as expected)
2. `sharedByChecks` is an object whose key is every `participant`, and value is either `true` or `false`, indicating if his/her checkbox should be checked or not.
   ex:

   {
   rahul:true,
   sam:false
   }
3. `t` is a copy whose value is map variable `friend`.
4. Now onclick of the checkbox, when I `console.log(temp)`, it is logging the value as expected, toggling between true and false.
5. then I update the `sharedByChecks` using `setSharedByChecks`, the state of the variable doesnt update, confirmed using the react dev tools extension. Hence even the checkbox doesnt change from checked to unchecked and vice versa.

Can someone point out where im going wrong? Do comment if u need some more information.

Comment: `let temp = { ...sharedByChecks };`;

Comment: In fact you can one-line the entire function: `onChange={(e) => setSharedByChecks({ ...sharedByChecks, [friend]: !sharedByChecks[friend] })`

Comment: Read https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Comment: Why did you use `key={Math.random()}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, which means that mutating them don't change the value of the variable storing them.

In your case, you reassign the state value to the previous value, which does *not* cause re-rendering, as React only re-renders when the state value actually changes.

Instead, you should create a new object like this:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setSharedByChecks(sharedByChecks => ({
        ...sharedByChecks,
        [friend]: !sharedByChecks[friend],
    }))
}}
```